# JFileChooser on a Button Click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jfilechooser

I have a button, clicking on which I want the JFileChooser to pop up. I have tried this

```
JButton browse= new JButton("Browse");
add(browse);
browse.addActionListener(new ClassBrowse());

public class ClassBrowse implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            try {
              // return the file path 
            } catch (Exception ex) {
              System.out.println("problem accessing file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
        }       
    }   
}
```

Bhe above gives error `The method showOpenDialog(Component) in the type JFileChooser is not applicable for the arguments (ClassName.ClassBrowse)`

Also, I want it to return the complete file path. How do I do so ?

Comment: Replace ``int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);`` with ``int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);``, assuming you have a JFrame set up somewhere, and that this is only part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

1. `ActionListener` is not a `Component`, you can't pass `this` to the file chooser.
2. You could look at [`File#getCanonicalPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29) to get the full path of the file, but you can't `return` it, as `actionPerformed` only returns a `void` (or no return type).  You could, however, set some other variable, call another method or even set the text of a `JLabel` or `JTextField` ... for example...

Answer (score 1):

You can set a instance variable which holds the file name string in the actionPerformed such as

```
private String fileName;
.......
your code
.......
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog((Component)e.getSource());
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
           fileName = file.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          System.out.println("problem accessing file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }       
}
```

Comment: Once you have a `File` don't turn it back to a `String`, that is nonsensical.

Comment: User specified that he wants the complete path

Comment: Which can easily be obtained from a `File` object.  So store the `File object.  Besides, sometimes the OP does not ask for the most logical thing, if they asked how to shoot themselves in the foot, would you give directions?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the container (It might be a JFrame, JDialog, JApplet or any) your JButton lies in to the

> fileChooser.showOpenDialog()

and the filechooser will open as a modal dialog on top of that container.